# Mysql Get_Lock and Release_Lock functions taking long time

Tags: java, mysql, database, innodb

We are trying to use MYSQL's locking function Get_Lock and Release_Lock in our spring java application . The code we are using is defined in a procedure for both seperately which simply invoke from our java code .The queries inside the proc are given below .

We have been monitoring the execution time of these functions and found that at times it takes a millisecond to execute but at other times , this takes around 400 to 600 ms . I have tried the following approaches but there hasn't been much of a difference : 
1. Use "Do" in place of select with these functions .
2. Using an int data type of the key which we are using as lock string .
3. Decreasing the length of lock string .

I am using a timeout of 0 to avoid connections being locked.

Can anyone please suggest me a way to optimize this .Is there a way of optimizing innodb buffer pool or something related to these configurations . 
Please do let me know if any other input is required from my end .

Please find below some proc code and stats for your reference .

Current Mysql Code :

Proc :

> get_Name_lock:

-- Using select

```
Select get_lock(Name,0) into c_Name_flag;
```

-- Using Do

```
Do get_lock(Name,0) ;
```

Proc :

> release_Name_lock :

-- Using select

```
Select release_lock(Name) into c_Name_flag;
```

-- Using Do

```
Do release_lock(Name);
```

Request rate : (around)10 requests/sec .
Mysql Version : 5.7.19-log

Comment: My first guess is that it's taking a while because another session is holding the lock, and the requesting session has to wait for it to be released. If many sessions are waiting for the lock, your session could take many milliseconds because it is waiting in a queue for the lock, and it has to wait until all other sessions do their work and release the lock. Since locks are exclusive, this work will be done one session at a time.

Comment: I would also reconsider any application design that uses `GET_LOCK()` extensively. This is usually not required when using a transactional storage engine. Just depend on optimistic locking done within transactions.

Comment: Bill its actually like we can set a timeout which prevents your incoming request to wait beyond a certain point .

Comment: You might do that using [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) and [max_execution_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time). See links to documentation.

Comment: What are you doing that might take so long?  Maybe we can approach the 'problem' from that side.